# Comparing element ids in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to compare two element ids in jQuery with the following code.

```
if($("#pic" + i).attr("id") == ($this.attr("id")))
```

If I try to retrieve the ids individually I can, but when I try to compare them within the if statement it crashes my script, and I'm not sure why.

EDIT: The entire piece of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideshow").click(function() {
        $("#pic0").attr('class', 'a');
        $("#pic6").attr('class', 'a');


        $(this).css('z-index', 1);
        $(".slideshow").animate({
            left: '10px'
        }, 1000);

        for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            alert($("#pic" + i).attr("id"));
            alert($(this).attr("id"));

            if ($("#pic" + i).attr("id") == ($this.attr("id"))) {
                $("#pic" + i).removeClass("boxShadow");
                alert("Doesn't");
            }
        }

        $("#contenttable").show();
        $("#contenttable").animate({
            width: '1200'
        }, 1000);
        $("#fadecontent").fadeIn(4000);

        $("#pic0").attr('attr', "slideshow");
        $("#pic6").attr('attr', "slideshow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use `$("#pic" + i).attr("id")` instead of `"pic" + i`?

Comment: `$("#pic" + i).attr("id")` always equal to `"pic" + i` (if the element exists)

Comment: I don't see a definition for `$this`.

Comment: (**$this**.attr("id")))  what is mean by `$this`

Comment: Have u tried using `$(this).attr("id")` instead of `$this.attr("id")`?

Comment: I was under the impression that this returned the element that activated the function, in this case the id will be something along the lines of "pic" + i where i is between 1 and 5.

Comment: All your loop can be replaced with `$(this).removeClass("boxShadow")`. You don't need to iterate over all elements at all

Comment: I want to remove all the elements' box shadows except for one. Everyone was right though, it should be $(this) instead of $this. Thanks all. I know that the == is incorrect for this, I changed it for testing purposes.

Comment: If you give the `picX` elements a common class, say `class="pic"`, you can get the result you want without the for loop: `$(".pic").not(this).removeClass("boxShadow");` (or you could do it for all elements that have an id starting with "pic" except the current one like this: `$('[id^=pic]').not(this).removeClass("boxShadow");`).

Comment: Accept an answer which helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are doing $this instead of $(this) inside your if statement....got darn php/jquery

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

instead of

```
$this.attr("id")
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code from

this

```
 if ($("#pic" + i).attr("id") == ($this.attr("id")))
```

to

```
 var pic_id = "pic" + i;
 if (pic_id == (this.id))
```

Comment: +1 for `this.id` when no jQuery is required.  Not sure why you have the extra parens though.

Comment: `this.id` is better than `$(this).attr("id")`, but why create the `pic_id` variable? Just use `if("pic" + i == this.id)`...